# How do I hide an element based on specific class and content with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, selector, contains

Hi there, I would like to hide some elements if a div with class **ms-searchref-categoryname** text contains **Job**:

```
 <div class="ms-searchref-categoryname">Job</div>

 <ul><li></li></ul>

 <a href=""><div class=""></div></a>
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Are you using a javascript framework such as jQuery or are you using plain old DOM.

Comment: Note that a block element (div) should not be inside a inline element (a): http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#block-inline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said "if div text *contains* something", you can use this:

```
if($(".ms-searchref-categoryname:contains('Job')").length > 0) {
   $("#elementToHide").hide();
}
```

This will hide the element if the string "Job" is found anywhere in the selected element. Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/E5hgp/).

Alternatively, without the use of the `:contains` pseudo-selector:

```
if($(".ms-searchref-categoryname").text().indexOf('Job') > -1) {
   $("#hideMe").hide();
}
```

On the other hand, if you meant you wanted to hide an element if a `div` *only* contains a specified string, then @Headshota has given you a working answer already.

Answer (score 3):

```
if($('.ms-searchref-categoryname').html() === 'Job'){
  $('.myElements').hide();
}
```

Comment: this will check for exact match `:)`